# DocuSign InPerson signature via NodeJS

Tags: docusignapi

I have combed through the DocuSign documentation but am unable to find a real world example.

I am looking for sample code that shows the InPerson signing flow via the docusign node client.

I am able to successfully create a new Signer and it works. I am unsure how to set that signer to InPerson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let inPersonSigner1 = docusign.InPersonSigner.constructFromObject({
    email: "enduseremail@domain.com",
    name: "end user name",
    hostEmail: "hostemail@doamain.com",
    hostName: "host name",
    recipientId: '1',
    routingOrder: '1'});

// Add the recipients to the envelope object
let recipients = docusign.Recipients.constructFromObject({
inPersonSigners: [inPersonSigner1]});
env.recipients = recipients;
```

The rest is the same as any other envelope, you can find the [remote signing example here](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-node/blob/master/lib/examples/eg002SigningViaEmail.js).

Note that the host must have a DocuSign account and they need to log-in to host the signer.